# CSS rotation not centered

Tags: html, css, rotation, css-transitions

So I've got this circle that is rotating on hover but it's not centered and I don't know why (I did add the 'transform-origin:center center')
And also, sorry I know very very little about css but what does it do/mean when there's two consecutive selectors pls?

Here's my code:

```css
#welcome:hover #welcomeavatar{
-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;  
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: rotate(180deg);
transform-origin : center center;
}

#welcome #welcomeavatar{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin : center center;
}
 
#welcome:hover #speechbubble{
-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
margin-left:120px;
}


#welcome #speechbubble{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#welcome #speechbubble{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="welcome">
<div id="welcomeavatar"><img src="http://www.for-example.org/img/main/forexamplelogo.png"></div>
<div id="speechbubble"></div>
```

The snippet isn't showing what's really happening but it's just so you can have my code and here's the real result : www.typhotoshop.tumblr.com

Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: It's off center because the element you are rotating (#welcomeavatar)  is display:block which takes up the full width of its container. Try adding a width to #welcomeavatar of 204px.

Comment: Actually you should give #welcomeavatar a width and a height of 200px (the same as your image). Then you need to add some styles to your image as well to get rid of the wobble. Make your image display:block and add a height/width of 200px as well.

Comment: Your image and the #welcomeavatar element do not match in dimensions, and your image is not square so even if you matched the dimensions rotating would not make it seamless. Your image has a natural resolution of 2630x2565, so there will be a slight wobble in the rotation.

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NjMdBy

Comment: Yes Michael thank you but I made it work with dmoz's answer! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rotation is actually around the center, but the div you're applying the rotation to is larger than your image. See screenshot below:

[image]

You'll want to make sure the div you're rotating is exactly the same size as the image inside(ie. remove width/height from that div altogether or add width/height that is the same as the image).

Also, the `margin-left` on the `#speechbubble` increases on the hover as well, so again, the rotating div moves left. Make that margin the same on hover and no-hover and it won't move.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, removing the width and height of div did work. Can you pls also tell me what putting two consecutive divs does if you have time? And about the margin it was on purpose!

Comment: Glad it worked. I'm not sure what you mean by "putting two consecutive divs". Putting them where? And why? Can you explain?

Comment: Like in this line :
#welcome #welcomeavatar{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin : center center;
}

There is two #, and I don't know the consequences of that?

Comment: The `#welcome #welcomeavatar` CSS with two IDs separated by a space selects any divs with the ID `#welcomeavatar` that are a descendent of `#welcome`. See here: https://css-tricks.com/how-css-selectors-work/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I don't know how to Stack Overflow.  My original comment as an actual answer:

It's off center because the element you are rotating (#welcomeavatar) is display:block which takes up the full width of its container. **Making it display inline-block is less than ideal because it can insert unwanted whitespace.**

You should give #welcomeavatar a width and a height of 200px (the same as your image). Then you need to add some styles to your image as well to get rid of the wobble. Make your image display:block and add a height/width of 200px as well.